# Ошибка с скриптом: "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php

Дело в том, что на обычном хосте все ок... но скрипт перехвата доменов ложит сервер. Заказал впс, но тут при запуске `root@73545:~# /usr/bin/php /var/www/drop_catch.php`
выдает

> `PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(drops.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/drop_catch.php on line 31`

В самом скрипте есть строчка `$file = "drops.txt"`; Я так понял, скрипт не может до него добраться... Оба файла `drop_catch.php` и `drops.txt` находятся в папке `var/www/`
доменное имя указанное в тхт файле верное, правда осободится сегодня ближе к вечеру...
Прошу вас, подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас /drop_catch.php файл лежит вместе с файлом drops.txt пропишите так -

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/drops.txt';
```

---

думаю поможет

Comment: вот так и написать без изменений, а то смущает `(__FILE__)`
может там что-то написать... в принципе, сейчас попробую

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: count in /var/www/drop_catch.php on line 48
вот что выдает

Comment: ну, не определена переменная $count

Comment: а как определить? и почему тогда на обычном хосте все выполнялось?)

Answer (score 0):

Ещё проверь права на папку. chmod